# Optimization and Modeling using Derivatives

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble getting started on a problem. I know the answer is m=50 n=50, but I am having troubles getting there.

```
The sum of two nonnegative numbers is 100. What is the maximum value of the product of these two numbers?
```

I started the problem stating:

$m+n=100$

$f(m)=100-n$ on [0, 100]

$f'(m)=-1$

as we know the critical points below I formulated:

$f(-1)=99$

$f(0)=100$

$f(100)=0$

With a global max of 100; global min of 0.

As of here I am stuck as to how I am to progress in this problem. I think I might be off in my initial approach, but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to maximize $mn$, not $100 - n$. Hence the relevant function to study is

$$f(m) = m (100 - m) = 100m - m^2$$

We have used the fact that $100 - m = n$, so this function really is just $mn$. Then the derivative is

$$f'(m) = 100 - 2m$$

and $50$ is a critical point.

Comment: How can you assume the two integers m are the same?

Comment: @BobDunakey What? There's no assumption that $m$ and $n$ are the same.

Comment: Oh, wait I got it after testing it on calculator. I assumed you were saying the two integers were the say on f(m). Thanks